# Simple Button to Magento 1.9 sales order view

Tags: php, magento

Im trying to add a simple button to the Magento Order. I tried the solution from stackoverflow but it is not working. This is my code, would be great if you can tell me what Im doing wrong. Thank you.

app/local/FirstGood/PrintCard/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php

```html
<?
class FirstGood_PrintCard_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View {
    public function  __construct() {
        
  parent::__construct();
        $this->addButton('button_id', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('xxx')->__('Some action'),
            'onclick'   => 'jsfunction(this.id)',
            'class'     => 'go'
        ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
    }
}
```

app/local/FirstGood/PrintCard/etc/config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
        <FirstGood_PrintCard>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </FirstGood_PrintCard>
    </modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
         <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>FirstGood_PrintCard_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
   <events>
        <adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
            <observers>
                <firstgood_printcard>
                    <class>firstgood_printcard/observer</class>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <method>adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore</method>
                </firstgood_printcard>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_widget_container_html_before>
    </events>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks> 
 </global>
 </config>
```

app/local/FirstGood/PrintCard/Model/Observer.php

```html
<?php 
class FirstGood_PrintCard_Model_Observer {
    public function adminhtmlWidgetContainerHtmlBefore($event)
{
    $block = $event->getBlock();

    if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View) {
        $message = Mage::helper('your_module')->__('Are you sure you want to do this?');
        $block->addButton('do_something_crazy', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('your_module')->__('Export Order'),
            'onclick'   => "confirmSetLocation('{$message}', '{$block->getUrl('*/yourmodule/crazy')}')",
            'class'     => 'go'
        ));
    }
}
}
```

app/etc/modules/FirstGood_PrintCard.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <FirstGood_PrintCard>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </FirstGood_PrintCard>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use "sales" helper, instead of "xxx". Use below code, it will help to fix this out.

app/local/FirstGood/PrintCard/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/View.php

```
<?
class FirstGood_PrintCard_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View {
    public function  __construct() {

       parent::__construct();
       $this->addButton('button_id', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Some action'),
        'onclick'   => 'jsfunction(this.id)',
        'class'     => 'go'
       ), 0, 100, 'header', 'header');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems, that this was a mistake, however it is still not displaying the button. But I think, that it is because other extensions are already adding buttons / manipulating buttons in this place. However if I change it in the core files its working... I really dont get it how something so simple is once again not working with magento.

Comment: Changing core file is not a good idea, try to avoid that. However when I tried your code, it worked perfectly for me. Might be it's caching issue, try to clear that and re-enable this module.

Comment: Where you mean to reenable it? In the backend? Cache is deactivated and was cleared dozens of times

Comment: I see. I meant to disable your module, and again enable it from the System->Configuration->Adavanced->Advanced tab.

Comment: That I have also done quite often, the button is appearing with you under sales>order>detail of an order? What can it be that its not happening. Else I will need to go with the core solution.

Comment: Yeah, it's frustrating lot of time. Sometime it behaves differently for different environments. This is what I am getting - https://www.evernote.com/l/AU4Qx9y02W5HUaN7YIXPCOJQyR8-jOcC7mw

Comment: I have used your posted code only. I can suggest to make sure path and file names are correct.